# Use `dplyr::filter_at` with multiple predicate expression

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Consider the following tibble.

```
 # A tibble: 5 x 3
 g1    g2     a
 <dbl> <dbl> <int>
  1     1     1     1
  2     1    NA     2
  3     2     1     3
  4     2     2     4
  5     2     2     5
```

I want to keep the rows if and only if (a) `g1 == 1` and `g2 == 1` and (b) `g1` and `g2` are not missing values. I can do this with `filter_at` and `all_vars`. See below.

```
df <- tibble(
  g1 = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  g2 = c(1, NA, 1, 2, 2),
  a = c(1 : 5)
)
df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("g")), all_vars(. == 1)) %>%
    filter_at(vars(starts_with("g")), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

My question is how to combine the two `filter_at` lines above into something like the following:

```
df %>% filter_at(vars(starts_with("g")), all_vars(. == 1) & all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

It seems `all_vars` or `any_vars` can take only one expression.

Comment: Based on my reading of the documentation, you should be able to use `&` inside `all_vars`: `all_vars(. == 1 & !is.na(.))`

Comment: @aosmith Can you add this as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&` inside `all_vars()` to use multiple conditions.

```
df %>%
     filter_at(vars(starts_with("g")), all_vars(. == 1 & !is.na(.) ) )

# A tibble: 1 x 3
     g1    g2     a
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     1     1     1
```

Comment: I think this works because you want the same condition to be true for each column value you test - that is, it is both ==1 and not NA. I tried to use this structure for a similar problem - find all rows where any value is either "A" or "B" and found that I could chain two filters: `filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "A"))) %>% filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "B")))` but not this way: `filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., "A") & str_detect(., "B")))`